Zonotope with Specefic Linear Constraint
Given a Constrained zonotope $\mathcal{Z} = \{ \mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^k \mid \mathbf{z} = \mathbf{G} \mathbf{x}, \ \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert\ _{\infty} \leq 1, \mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{x} = 0 \}$ is there a possible to enumerate all vertices in similar run-time as a standard zonotope, which is $\mathcal{O}(n^{k-1})$? The hyperplane itself can be represented as a zonotope however we still run into trouble as intersection of two zonotope might not be a zonotope.
